# The curve $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ can be parameterized if and only if $x^3+Ax+B$ has a repeated root.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametrization

I'm working through Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry,* and one of the problems asks the reader to prove the problem in the title. I found the "if" direction fairly straightforward, but I can't finish my proof of the converse. If anyone can help me finish it, that'd be greatly appreciated! Suppose we have the rational parametrization $$(\frac{f(t)}{g(t)})^2=(\frac{p(t)}{q(t)})^3+A\frac{p(t)}{q(t)}+B,$$
yielding the identity $$f(t)^2q(t)^3=g(t)^2[p(t)^3+Aq(t)^2p(t)+Bq(t)^3].$$ Assuming $f$ and $g$ are coprime, we find that $p(t)^3+Aq(t)^2p(t)+Bq(t)^3$ must have a square factor.

From here, I know that either two of the $(p(t)-aq(t)), (p(t)-bq(t)),$ and $(p(t)+(a+b)a(t)$ are the same, or, as @Aphelli pointed out, there are repeated factors. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to show this second case isn't so. If anyone can help me finish this, or give an alternative solution, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Completely changed the question to account for the fact that the proof is, in fact, incomplete, and I cannot finish it.

Comment: At least upon a quick read-through, your argument seems correct. IANAL! :) ... but, to my mind more significantly, what you've proven is a special case of the _qualitative_ point (which I learned from Joe Lipman c. 1972) that genus of algebraic curves cannot increase under (reasonable) maps. So a parametrization would be a map from a genus $0$ curve to a positive-genus curve, which is impossible. :)

Comment: I don’t think it’s necessary that two among $p-aq$, $p-bq$ and $p+(a+b)q$ have to be the same… you could just have repeated factors between them, or they could have multiple factors… no?

Comment: @Aphelli I know it has been a while since you posted your comment, but I think I've finally found a way of fixing my proof (or maybe I really need to go to sleep). Instead of considering the $f, g, p,$ and $q$ as polynomials, could we consider them as abstract variables satisfying the identity? Therefore the irreducible factors would actually be irreducible? If I'm way off, do you think you could give me a hint for the correct solution (if you know it, of course)?

Comment: I don’t think you can treat the polynomial as formal variables here: after all, they satisfy some relations! What you can say, though, is that $f$ is coprime to $g$, hence $f^2$ divides $(p-aq)(p-bq)(p+(a+b)q)$. On the other hand, since $p,q$ are coprime, all of these factors are coprime to $q$ so the product divides $f^2$. Now, if $X^3+AX+B$ is separable, then $p-aq, p-bq, p+(a+b)q$ are pairwise coprime polynomials whose product is (associated to) a square. So each of these factors is (associated to) a square. This might be enough to derive a contradiction.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you very much for pointing out that the proof had a flaw in it! I tried following up on your suggestion, but I really cannot get it to work, and I've edited the question to reflect that. Just figured I'd let you know, in case you want to write an answer (obviously no pressure though). Again, thank you for what you've already done!

Comment: Actually, I forgot a very important piece – because it’s easy to find coprime $p,q$ such that $p-aq,p-bq,p+(a+b)q$ are all squares. The same argument shows that $q^3=g^2$, so that $q$ *also* has to be a square. Now *that* should be enough to find the contradiction (although I’m not sure about the precise argument afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrea Mori gives a good abstract argument (that reflects what is really going on). Here’s an elementary one.

*Lemma*: let $k$ be an algebraically closed field with $2 \in k^{\times}$. Let $V \subset k[x]$ be a plane. Then $V$ does not contain four nonzero, pairwise non-associated squares.

*Proof*: by induction on the maximal degree $\delta$ of a polynomial $P \in V$. Clearly $\delta \geq 2$.
So let $\delta \geq 2$ be minimal contradicting the statement. Then we can find $V$ and squares $p,q,p-q,p+\lambda q \in V$ with $\lambda \neq 0,-1$. Clearly, the gcd of $p,q$ is $1$, because it is a square and we could divide everything by it, contradicting the minimality of $\delta$.

Write $p=u^2,q=v^2$, then $u$ and $v$ have degree less than $\delta$, and are coprime. Moreover, $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v)$ is a square and $u-v,u+v$ are coprime, so $u+v,u-v$ are squares. Write $\lambda=-\mu^2$, then $p+\lambda q=(u-\mu v)(u+\mu v)$ with $\mu\neq 0,\pm 1$. For the same reason, $u-\mu v,u+\mu v$ are squares.

Thus $ku+kv$ contains the four nonzero squares $u\pm v, u\pm \mu v$, contradicting the minimality of $\delta$.

**Corollary**: the equation $y^2=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ has no rational parametrization when $a,b,c$ are pairwise distinct.

*Proof*: assume that we have $(f/g)^2=(p/q-a)(p/q-b)(p/q-c)$ where $f,g,p,q$ are polynomials with $gq\neq 0$ and $(f,g)=(p,q)=1$. Then we have $f^2q^3=g^2(p-aq)(p-bq)(p-cq)$.

By my comments, it follows that $(p-aq)(p-bq)(p-cq)$ (resp. $g^2$) is associated to $f^2$ (resp. $q^3$). Since $a,b,c$ are pairwise disjoint, $p-aq,p-bq,p-cq$ are pairwise coprime, hence every one of them is a square; since $q^3$ is associated to $g^2$, $q$ is a square. Hence the plane $kp+kq$ contradicts the lemma.

Comment: I'm confused about your first lemma. When you write "let $V$ be a plane," doesn't that immediately imply it has degree $1$? Also, if we did have more than three squares in $V,$ why would they have to be of the form $p, q, p-q,$ and $p+\lambda q$ with $p, q$ coprime?

Comment: By “plane”, I mean “vector subspace of dimension two”, so there’s no degree constraint here. The phrasing of the lemma is incorrect and I need to re-write it more carefully: the idea is that among your four squares, you can have a basis $(p,q)$ of $V$, then the others are linear combinations of $p,q$. You then rescale $p,q$ and these linear combinations so that they’re actually $p-q$ and $p+\lambda q$. This is free since every scalar is a square.

Comment: I see! Thank you for clarifying. Just to make sure I understand, the degree of $V$ is the degree of the vector basis?

Comment: I meant “maximal degree of a polynomial in $V$”, I edited to clarify.

Comment: I know you answered this a really long time ago, but I recently remembered this problem, and I've been wondering how you came up with your lemma. The proof itself seems pretty easy, but how did you get the idea that the lemma itself was necessary? And in that particular form? Apologies if this sounds annoying or nonsensical, I would just like to understand where you got this idea.

Comment: In fact, I just wrote the proof I wanted to write – “suppose there is a parametrization, then… “ – and we get $f^2q^3=g^2(p-aq)(p-bq)(p-cq)$. This is only possible if $p-aq,p-bq,p-cq,q$ are all squares. So I wanted to show that this was impossible. Hence the lemma.

Answer (score 2):

If the cubic $E$ is singular, after a suitable change of coordinates you can always assume that the origin $O=(0,0)$ is the singular point. Then the parametrization is obtained by associating each line $\ell$ in the pencil through $O$ to the third point $P$ of intersection in $\ell\cap E$. Since a pencil of line through a point is a copy of the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$, this geometric construction defines a birational isomorphism
$$
\mathbb{P}^1\longleftrightarrow E.
$$
If the cubic is smooth, by taking any point $P\in E$ and doing the same construction we obtain a $2$-to-$1$ map
$$
E\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}^1
$$
whose ramification points correspond to the lines through $P$ that are tangent to $E$. Of these there are $4$, for instance if we take as $P$ the point at infinity for the standard Weierstrass model of $E$ the $4$ tangents are the $3$ vertical lines that go through the points of $E$ with $x$-coordinate equal to $0$, i.e. the points of $2$-torsion of $E$, and the line at infinity itself.

From this situation one obtains that $E$ must be of genus $1$ and in particular that its function field is not a purely trascendental extension of the base field with degree $1$.

Therefore the curve $E$ does not admit a rational parametrization.